# Databricks Jobs Webhook Notification ID

Tags: databricks, databricks-rest-api, databricks-workflows

I want to set a **webhook notification** for a job using the Jobs API.
According to the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsCreate) I need the notification ID, but where do I get that from?
Is that the essentially the webhook configuration name?

> An optional list of notification IDs to call when the run fails. A
> maximum of 3 destinations can be specified for the on_failure
> property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These IDs are IDs of the Alerts Destinations that you created via UI. You can fetch the destination ID from the URL when you're accessing specific alert in UI.  This feature right now is in the private preview, so for detailed specification please reach someone from Databricks.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but aren't Alerts used for DBSQL queries instead of jobs? I am looking for the 
notification destination ID from a webhook that I have configured through Admin console, so that I receive a notification on failure of my jobs.

Comment: sorry, mixed up things - alerts destinations API isn't documented yet, so you can only get it from the UI - the UUID between `/sql/destinations/` and next `/` (I've updated answer)

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. Another way to retrieve the destination ID that I found is the "View Job as JSON" feature.